# Is this a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

Let us say that we have shape AXQY:
[image: Shape AXQY: NOT TO SCALE]

And line AX is congruent to AQ. Line QY is congruent to XY.
I do not believe that we have enough information to say whether this is a parallelogram or not, because we do not know if side AX is congruent to QY and AQ is congruent to XY. So, if this is a square, it is a parallelogram. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily a parallelogram. Take two isosceles triangles sharing a base for example. Face them away from eachother to make it convex if you like.

[image]

Comment: yes, that is right